# "Grub" error al instalar Kubuntu

Tags: linux

Estoy desde la versión de prueba del Kubuntu. Resulta que decidí instalarlo y todo perfecto, pero cuando se pone a trabajar para instalarme Kubuntu sale el error:

Executing 'grub-install /dev/sda' failed. This is a fatal error.

Estoy eligiendo mal la partición, que onda?
Eso que le deje de partición 150 gb y 50mb para el ELI, que son lógicas.

Answer (score 0):

Yo te recomiendo la siguiente partición:

Partición primaria:

boot 1 GB

Particiones extendidas:

swap El doble de la memoria RAM, home El resto del disco y para el sistema / 50 GB

Tener el boot muy pequeño al momento de actualizar no habrá más espacio y tendrás que borrar manualmente cada kernel antiguo.